# How to Use session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

hiii..am doing  a  survey project. i have a text box and two ajax calendar extender. i want to use Survey name as session. How to do that?? am not familiar with session. can anyone help me please???

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strcon;
        strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SurveyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(strcon);
        com2.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        com2.CommandText = "insert into SurveyMaster1(SurveyName,DateCreated,ExpiredDate) VALUES(@SurveyName,@DateCreated,@ExpiredDate)";
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurveyName", txtSurveyName.Text);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCreated", txtCreaDate.Text);
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiredDate", txtExDate.Text);
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Inserted Successfully");
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Questions.aspx");
}
}
```

aspx code:

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Survey Name"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Expired Date"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurveyName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCreaDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtCreaDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtCreaDate">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtExDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtExDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtExDate">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SAVE" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFieldSurvey" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtSurveyName" ErrorMessage="* Enter Survey Name" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 458px; top: 99px; position: absolute; bottom: 286px"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqCreDate" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtCreaDate" ErrorMessage="* Select Date" >   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqExpDate" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="txtExDate" ErrorMessage="* Select Date"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to use Survey name as session

If you want to create a session with key as Survey Name then you do this

```
string surveyName = txtsurvey.Text;
Session["SurveyName"] = surveyName;  // or whatever value, you want to assign in session object.
```

Comment: You'll want a *fixed* key for that session value, else you will not find the value again.

Answer (score 3):

Set: `Session["SurveyName"] = "A survey name";`

Get: `txtSurveyName.Text = Session["SurveyName"].ToString();`

Answer (score 3):

add this code in your .cs file it store your textbox value in session
  and for your information session stores any type of value because it is of type 'object'

```
Session["SurveyName"] = TextBox.text;
```

Hope this will help you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first step if you want to gain more familiarity with the Session object should probably be to read up on the MSDN documentation, at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524319.aspx.

To use the session in your code, simply assign to it, thus:

```
    con.Close();
    Session["SurveyName"] = txtSurveyName.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Questions.aspx");
```

You are then able to use Session["SurveyName"] in later pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Survey name in Session Name in this way : -

```
Session["SurveyName"] = txtSurveyName.Text;
```

and when you want to use Survey name you can get in this way :-

```
string StrSurveyName = Session["SurveyName"].ToString();
```

Hope this will Help You